# Empty value within data validation dropdown

Tags: google-sheets

After adding data validation to the cell with 'list of items' I've stuck to add 'empty value' to the list of valid items.
By for selecting 'empty value' I expect to clear the cell.
Is that possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was able to achieve the look of a blank drop down option by using the **left-to-right mark (LRM)** Unicode character copied to my clipboard from another document.

I was able to copy the character from one of these sites:

- [emptycharacter.com](https://emptycharacter.com/)
- [www.unicode-symbol.com/u/200E.html](http://www.unicode-symbol.com/u/200E.html)

And test it at https://apps.timwhitlock.info/unicode/inspect.

[image]

Tried creating a snippet on Stack Overflow but it seemed to strip the character out.

Comment: A Zero-Width Space also worked for me (the LRM is harder to select and copy). The ZWS is within these two brackets >​< — copy/paste both brackets, delete the brackets, and you will notice the cursor stops in the middle when moving over the space.

Answer (score 8):

I have managed to do this by adding a single quote <'> to a blank cell.
It works for me as shown here:
[image: screenshot]

On selecting this it shows up as a blank line.

Comment: This works, or also if the Data Validation's Criteria is [List of items] containing the ' character.

Answer (score 2):

This doesn't seem possible. Empty strings are ignored if they are provided among the options; this happens both directly in a spreadsheet and when building validation rules from an array of strings via Apps Script. This is probably because validation rules are ignored when the cell is empty, so allowing an empty string would be redundant. Unfortunately, this also means you can't have an empty string in a in-cell dropdown.

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this by adding a special space character within Excel environment. To do this:

1. Select any empty cell in your Excel table;
2. Click [Insert] tab;
3. Choose [Symbol] and then switch to [Special Characters] tab;
4. Select any "Space" symbol you like, I prefer "En Space", and click [Insert];
5. Select and copy (Ctrl+C) that "space" from the input line of Excel with your mouse;
6. Input that copied "space" into [Source] line of your [Data Validation].

Answer (score -2):

I'm not sure if you're still on the hunt for a solution to this problem, but if so, I have one.

Before following these steps, ensure your data validation reference has a blank cell somewhere in the table, preferably the first or last cell.

Once you're finished:

1. Select a cell with data validation
2. Go to Data > Data Tools > Data Validation
3. In the window that pops up, navigate to the "Source" section

(Note that, even though you likely selected the range including the blank cell, it wasn't applied.)

4. For example, if your source looks like `=Sheet1!$A$3:$A$14` ($A$2 should be the blank cell) after setting up data validation, edit it to include the blank cell (e.g. change $A$3 to $A$2.)

That should be it.

Comment: This solution isn't working anymore. After editing, the source again changes back to A3 instead of retaining A2.